# Error installing telethon with pip3 install telethon

Tags: python, pip, python-telegram-bot, telethon

When i try to install telethon from pip3 i got this error, why?
I run this in a windows 10 of 32 bits in the cmd.

```
C:\Users\JUAN>pip3 install telethon

Collecting telethon
  Using cached Telethon-1.16.4-py3-none-any.whl (483 kB)
Collecting pyaes
  Using cached pyaes-1.6.1.tar.gz (28 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\JUAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i2of7eld\\pyaes\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\JUAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i2of7eld\\pyaes\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\JUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-pffewwkh'
         cwd: C:\Users\JUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i2of7eld\pyaes\
    Complete output (24 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2867, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map
      File "c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2825, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _ep_map

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\JUAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i2of7eld\pyaes\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        setup(name = 'pyaes',
      File "c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 423, in __init__
        for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
      File "c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 657, in <genexpr>
        for entry in dist.get_entry_map(group).values()
      File "c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2869, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map = EntryPoint.parse_map(
      File "c:\users\juan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2550, in parse_map
        raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
    ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: go where pip.exe is located and try to run the command from there

Comment: That didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by uninstalling python and pip, the python version I had was 3.8.5 and the latest version is 3.8.9.

Comment: the newest python version as of 10/6/2020 is 3.8.6, not 3.8.9

Comment: Check the website xd

Comment: the newest version is 3.9, sorry :), must have been released today, or late yesterday